# How to set viewport height and width in Cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to limit viewport, where the nodes can be dragged and displayed to full hd resolution (1920×1080 px). Is it possible with cy.resize() function? I've tried to set cy.resize({width: 1920px, height: 1080px}), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS on your container.

If you [read the docs for `cy.resize()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.resize), you'll notice it just syncs with CSS changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom CSS also when you add graphs in HTML.
Like

```
 <div class="col" [hidden]="noGraph">
    <div id="cy" class="bg-white graph-dynamic-height"></div>
</div>
```

and in CSS

```
.graph-dynamic-height {
    height: calc(100vh - 215px);
}
```

The above code work for me.